# org.springframework.core.env.Environment along with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: properties, configuration, environment

When a properties file is placed externally, then can we use org.springframework.core.env.Environment to access that properties file?

```
@Autowired
public Environment env;

String propertyValue= env.getProperty(key);
```

Any example/tutorial link will be helpful. 
I have seen how @ConfigurationProperties can be used with @PropertySource, but here the properties file is at an external location and I want to use Environment instead of a POJO with @Component